# Open Material UI Dialogs from Parent Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I need to open two seperate Material UI dialogs (Terms & Privacy) from their parent component which is a material UI 'simple menu'. I have them imported and nested in the parent already, I just don't know how to get them to open from their parent while being seperate files. I played around with [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60474776/how-can-i-open-material-ui-modal-from-parent-component) for way too long but couldn't get it working. Thanks.

Parent component (Menu):

```
import React from 'react';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MoreVertIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoreVert';
import Terms from './Terms';
import Privacy from './Privacy'

const More = () => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton
        aria-label="more"
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
        edge='end'
      >
        <MoreVertIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Terms of Use</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Privacy Policy</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      <Terms />
      <Privacy />
    </div>
  );
}

export default More;
```

Child component 1 ('Terms' dialog):

```
import React from 'react';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const Terms = () => {

  const [openTerms, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const openTermsDialog = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleCloseTerms = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={openTerms}
      onClose={handleCloseTerms}
      aria-labelledby="terms-dialog-title"
      aria-describedby="terms-dialog-description"
    >
      <DialogTitle id="terms-dialog-title">{"Terms of Use"}</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText id="terms-dialog-description">
          Terms go here
        </DialogContentText>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleCloseTerms} color="primary" autoFocus>
          Agree
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  )
}

export default Terms;
```

Child component 2 ('Privacy' dialog):

```
import React from 'react';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const Privacy = () => {

  const [openPrivacy, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpenPrivacy = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClosePrivacy = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={openPrivacy}
      onClose={handleClosePrivacy}
      aria-labelledby="privacy-dialog-title"
      aria-describedby="privacy-dialog-description"
    >
      <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Privacy Policy"}</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <DialogContentText id="privacy-dialog-description">
         Privacy policy goes here
        </DialogContentText>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleClosePrivacy} color="primary" autoFocus>
          Agree
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  )
}

export default Privacy;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just lift up the state from the dialog components to the parent component, and pass it down to the child components.

```
  const More = () => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [openDialogName, setOpenDialog] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const openTermsDialog = () => {
    setOpenDialog('TERMS');
    handleClose();
  };

  const openPrivacyDialog = () => {
    setOpenDialog('PRIVACY');
    handleClose();
  };

  const closeDialog = () => {
    setOpenDialog(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
        {/* ... */}
        <MenuItem onClick={openTermsDialog}>Terms of Use</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={openPrivacyDialog}>Privacy Policy</MenuItem>
        {/* ... */}
      <Terms open={openDialogName === 'TERMS'} onClose={closeDialog} />
      <Privacy open={openDialogName === 'PRIVACY'} onClose={closeDialog} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default More;
```

And in Privacy for example (and the same idea for Terms as well):

```
const Privacy = ({ open, onClose }) => {
  return (
    <Dialog
      open={open}
      onClose={onClose}
    >
    {/* ... */}
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks @MartinHorváth that worked well! now im just getting two no-unused-vars warnings each in Privacy.js and Terms.js for openTerms, handleOpenTerms & openPrivacy, handleOpenPrivacy. anything that could be done about that?

Comment: Those won't be needed then, you do not use those variables, because you are controlling the dialog from the parent dialog, so just delete all of them :)

Comment: makes sense but now theres a "TypeError: setOpen is not a function. (In 'setOpen(false)', 'setOpen' is false)" on either child when using handleClosePrivacy or handleCloseTerms to close the dialog with the built in button. I assume because its not getting set to true when the dialog opens?

Comment: never mind I just used your {onClose} for the onClick property. thanks a lot! 

Comment: Then I would be grateful if you would accept my answer as accepted :)